# Profile memory usage of iOS File Provider extension

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios-app-extension, fileprovider-extension

We want to profile the memory usage of the File Provider extension of our iOS app using Instruments. A File Provider extension only has access to a limited amount of RAM (currently 15MB on iOS 17), thus optimizing memory usage is important because the system kills the extension process if it tries to allocate more memory.

So, how can we profile the memory usage of a File Provider extension?

Ideally, I would imagine something like this to be possible:

1. Install optimized build to device via Xcode.
2. Launch Instruments, select Allocations template and make Instruments wait for the extension to be launched.
3. We open up the Files app on device and start browsing the extension contents.
4. Extension process is launched and Instruments is attached to it to record allocations.

Is something like this possible? How can this be done?